# Copy Constructor for c++/cx ref class having native C++ pointer.

Tags: c++, c++-cx, winrt-component

I have a C++/CX ref class that contains a pointer of an un-managed C++ class. The ref class don't need any copy constructor because they are managed by reference buy should I need to write the copy constructor of the ref class in this case to avoid any shallow copy of that un-managed pointer?

Answer (score 1):

The C++ compiler enforces the reference type behavior of a `ref class`. And does so by *not* auto-generating a copy constructor and assignment operator like it does for a regular C++ class.  If you *try* to copy-construct you'll be slapped by:

> class "Foo::Bar" has no suitable copy constructor

So no, intentionally `= delete` is not necessary.  Client languages that use your ref class will have the same restriction.